# Aplicar No Case Sensitive a carpetas/directorios web

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting, dominio, mod-rewrite

Hace un tiempo hice [esta pregunta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51654884/9609518) sin obtener respuesta.

Sucede que estoy aplicando la regla `RewriteRule [NC]` a *misitio.com* para que, independientemente de la escritura, mayúscula o minúscula, me acepte la petición en la URI.

Tengo la siguiente configuración en mi archivo `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitio.com/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Funciona para el dominio principal, pero no para las carpetas o directorios (p. ej. *misitio.com/contacto*)

Según la [documentación de Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) esta instrucción debería funcionar de forma global. Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [A-Z] 

RewriteRule (.*) http://${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Vi la opción de aplicar esta regla a cada directorio de forma independiente, pero las páginas se crean de forma dinámica y controlarlas de esta manera no me parece la mejor opción.

También vi [esta respuesta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967482/9609518), pero no termino de entenderla del todo para aplicar a mi sitio. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: es para las rutas y nombres de archivo? `protocolo://subdominio.dominio.tld:puerto/ruta/archivo`

Comment: Están definidos en carpetas, son subdirectorios

Comment: Por ejemplo `misitio.com/contacto` donde `contacto` es en realidad el nombre del directorio, dentro de ese directorio tengo un `index.php` al que ingresa automáticamente debido a su nombre, claro está. La ruta sería así: `misitio.com/contacto/index.php`

Comment: edita la pregunta haciendo click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/242826/edit) así queda claro que es para carpetas y archivos ( no subdominios )

Comment: tenes acceso al servidor para habilitar módulos ? onda `$ a2enmod speling` te permite habilitar el [módulo corrector](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) y limitarlo a mayúsculas/minúsculas con `CheckCaseOnly on`

Comment: No, no tengo acceso, ya lo solicité y lo único que me habilitaron fue el .htaccess en la raiz del sitio

Comment: Esto se suele hacer con `RewriteMap`, pero si no tienes acceso al archivo de configuración de Apache no podrás escribir esa directiva. En hosting compartido hay restricciones en ese sentido. Si efectivamente no lo puedes hacer desde la configuración (por falta de acceso) no te quedará otra salida que poner la redirección manual en el `.htaccess` de cada carpeta de tu sitio. De todos modos es extraño tener un sitio que ¿crea? carpetas de forma dinámica...

Comment: Es una platilla en php que se alimenta desde un json. Muchos usuarios lo van modificando y lo suben por medio de un cliente FTP, lo básico. Por eso se me sale un poco de control redireccionarlos manualmente. Pero te agradezco si pudieras ofrecerme esa alternativa en una respuesta @A.Cedano

Comment: Mira [las tres opciones que explican aquí](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#Htaccess_Redirect_Uppercase_Lowercase). Yo tengo funcionando la primera, pero sólo en el directorio raíz de mi sitio, si intento implementarla en subdirectorios no me funciona. Las otras serían las más idóneas, pero sólo las puedes implementar si tienes acceso al archivo de configuración de Apache.

Comment: creo que podrías manejar mejor el tema carpetas y nombres de archivo, dándoles a los usuarios un par user/clave de ftp que les haga entrar en otra carpeta ( no en el public_html ) y desde php buscas en esa carpeta, haces las conversiones de case y el mapeado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según lo expuesto en [*Htaccess to Redirect Uppercase to Lowercase de askapache*](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#CW), hay al menos tres formas de forzar que todo lo escrito en la barra del navegador sea convertido a minúscula.

Todo dependerá de si tienes accesso al archivo de configuración de Apache o no (generalmente en hosting compartido no te dan acceso a ese archivo).

### Si no tienes acceso al archivo de configuración

#### [Directamente en el archivo `.htaccess`](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#Htaccess_Redirect_Uppercase_Lowercase)

En ese caso puedes poner estas reglas, teniendo en cuenta que esto debería ir en la parte superior de tu archivo `.htaccess`. Al menos debería ir por encima de cualquier otra `RewriteRule`. Esto se debe a que utiliza un bucle, hasta que no haya más caracteres en mayúsculas para convertir, seguirá comenzando en la primera regla de reescritura de `HASCAPS: TRUE`. Esto es realmente muy rápido y no va a ralentizar nada.

Tengo esto implementado en mi sitio y funciona sin problemas. Aunque no he podido hacerlo funcionar en sub directorios, sí funciona en el root de mi sitio. Mi problema era que crée un programa para guardar la cantidad de visitas de mi sitio por cada URL usando la API de Google Analytics y no podía hacer bien los filtros por URL cuando el usuario escribía usando alguna mayúscula... actualmente todo lo que entra el sitio llega en minúscula.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Si hay mayúsculas, establezca HASCAPS en verdadero y omita la siguiente regla
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Omita esta sección completa si no hay letras en mayúsculas en la URL solicitada
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Reemplace la ocurrencia individual de CAP con cap, luego procese la siguiente Regla.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# Si hay letras en mayúsculas, reinicie en la primera RewriteRule en el archivo
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

### Si tienes acceso al archivo de configuración

Puedes hacerlo mediante cualquiera de estas dos formas:

#### [Usando `RewriteMap` en el archivo `httpd.conf`](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#RewriteMap_httpd-conf)

Esto es técnicamente una forma más rápida de hacerlo, pero tiene que estar en el archivo `httpd.conf`, no en `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

#### [Usando `mod_speling`](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#mod_speling_httpd-conf)

También puedes habilitar el módulo apache [`mod_speling`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html), del siguiente modo:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckCaseOnly On
    CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
```

---

### Otras opciones

Dado que dices que en tu contexto de alguna manera *se crean directorios libremente por los usuarios*, quizá sería recomendable controlar el código que crea esos directorios, haciendo que los contenidos sean creados en directorios ya fijados. En cuanto a los URLs, también podrías controlar para que éstas sean creadas siempre en minúsculas, por ejemplo, por promación PHP controlar siempre que los nombres y extensiones de archivos sean convertidos a minúscula antes de guardarlos en el servidor.

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente con su primera opción. Muchas gracias por su respuesta tan completa y su sugerencia final